# Simulating a level in Flutter using gyroscope / accelerator

Tags: animation, flutter, dart, gravity, gyroscope

I'm fairly new to Flutter, and I'm trying to create a Widget whose background acts as a level (similar to the iOS Compass app, or similar to the background in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IIoa9uNka_0) project). I added the AeyriumSensor package and so I can access the pitch and roll of the device, however I'm not sure on how to go about starting to create such a Widget to behave accordingly, possibly using the `Transform` widget.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

**Edit**: I have made some progress; I am now defining the shape use four vertices:

```
p1 = [0.0, h]
p2 = [w, h]
p3 = [w, fluidHeight * angle + fluidHeight]
p4 = [0.0, -1 * fluidHeight * angle + fluidHeight]

w := deviceSize.width
h := deviceSize.height
fluidHeight = percentFilled * h
```

This somewhat works, however only accurately works at 50%, with the shape's tilt moving too extremely when < 50% and too subtley when > 50%, so I'm not too sure how to adjust the equations to acccomodate for this.

Comment: The aeyrium_sensor package has an example project on its github. You should look at that for ideas.

Comment: @Abion47 the example project is trivial; it just simply prints the pitch and roll which I can easily do

Comment: The pitch and roll is all you need to create a level app. If you're asking how to render the object, you could use `Transform`, or perhaps `Stack` and `Positioned`, or perhaps even roll your own widget type with a `CustomPainter` implementation. There are a bunch of ways to do this, and no one way is objectively the best. Do some research and come up with your own solution using the method you like the most.

Comment: @Abion47 ya I am asking how to render such an object. How should I get started with Transform (ie what equations and transformations should I make using the roll and pitch?) I'm not sure how to find any resources for this

Comment: No one can show you how to do this without straight-up doing it for you, and that's a big ask for a bunch of volunteers on a Q&A site. The pitch and roll translate virtually directly to X offset and Y offset of the level's bubble, and that's essentially all you need to know. Throw in some trig if you want, but it may not even be necessary. Exactly how much is going to depend on how you set up your UI and how far from level you are planning to render. This isn't a "show me a tutorial on how exactly to do it" thing. It's a "do it, then fine-tune it until it works the way you want" kind of thing.